# Leap year solution check

Tags: javascript, leap-year

I know there are better and more efficient solutions to check which year is a leap year. But I'm a beginner and I'm curious, despite my code being inefficient, does it still carry out the solution and its logic isn't flawed?

**This is how to work out whether a particular year is a leap year:**

A year is a leap year if it is evenly divisible by 4 ;

except if that year is also evenly divisible by 100;

unless that year is also evenly divisible by 400.

**My solution:**

```js
function isLeap(year) {   

    if (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 != 0) {
        return "Leap year.";
    }

    if (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 != 0 && year % 400 === 0) {
        return "Leap year.";
    }

    if (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 != 0 && year % 400 != 0) {
        return "Not leap year.";
    }

    else {
        return "Not leap year.";
    }
}
```

Comment: `!!((year % 400 === 0) + (year % 4 === 0) - (year % 100 === 0))`

Comment: `new Date(yr, 1, 29, 12, 0, 0).getMonth() === 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have 3 if statements separately. The 3rd if-statement, regardless of the outcome, will log "Not a leap year", so `year % 400 !=0` is a redundant check to make, because if removed, it will still fall under the `else` comparison.

Meaning we can put everything that is not a leap year into the `else` and eliminate the if statement, making the code look like this.

```
if (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 != 0) {
    return "Leap year.";
}

if (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 != 0 && year % 400 === 0) {
    return "Leap year.";
}

else {
    return "Not leap year.";
}
```

and if we look at the remaining if statements, we can see that the first 2 comparisons are identical, and we have an optional check of `year % 400 === 0`.

However, according to your 3 rules, the 3rd rule states:
`unless that year is also evenly divisible by 400.`
So we can assume that if it it divisible by 400, it's a guaranteed leap year and we have the statement `year % 400 === 0` ensuring that. Then we follow that with an OR operator, `||`. This means that if we ever get a year that is divisible by 400, we always return that its a leap year regardless of the other 2 rules.

However, if its not divisible by 400, we have the 2 remaining comparisons `year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 === 0`. And if these both are true, enforced by the AND operator, `&&`, then it's also a leap year. Which would leave you with the following if statement.

```
if (year % 400 === 0 || year % 100 !== 0 && year % 4 === 0) {
    return "Leap year.";
}

else {
    return "Not leap year.";
}
```

At this point, you could say that a year will either enter the if statement by being true and falling under the rules of being a leap year. Meaning we could remove the `else` and just have an if statement and an extra return afterwards that will never be reached if the function is called with a valid leap year.

```
if (year % 400 === 0 || year % 100 !== 0 && year % 4 === 0) {
    return "Leap year.";
}

return "Not leap year.";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply implement all the `conditions` in one line.
Learn about [Logical AND (&&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) and [Logical OR (||)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)

```js
function isLeap(year) {

    //conditions to find out the leap year
    if ((0 == year % 4) && (0 != year % 100) || (0 == year % 400)) {
        console.log(year + ' is a leap year');
    } else {
        console.log(year + ' is not a leap year');
    }
}

// take user input
const year = prompt('Enter a year:');

isLeap(year);
```

Comment: Refering to the original document is always appreciated.

Comment: @Helio What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
const leapYear = (year) => {
    let checkYear = "";
    const isLeap = (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0;
    return isLeap ? (checkYear = "a Leap Year") : (checkYear = "not a Leap Year");
};

console.log(leapYear(2001));
```